# How to make Samba serve a single File next to other Share Definitions

Tags: samba, shared-folders, shared-file

For sake of convinience, I'd like samba to share a file next to the other defined directories.
Windows Users can access my samba shares by going to "Network" -> "STORAGE".
In there, are some folders, like "Pictures", "Music", "Documents", etc.

I'd like to create an executable file within that folder as well.
The file would be named "Server-Management.url" and points to a locally accessible website: http://STORAGE/index.html

Could anyone explain how to create such a file?
I've tried to use the share definition name **[Server-Management.url]**, pointing to a file which has the following content, but it didn't work:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://STORAGE/index.html
```

Maybe it's also possible to set a custom Icon for that file as well.

Please don't just close this as off-topic or stuff like that, it's a serious question from a customer.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, Windows doesn't support having files alongside shares so it can't be done.  The closest you can get that I am aware of is to create a "Server Management" share that points to an empty folder on the Samba server, and put your `.url` file inside that.